# Etrecheck says performance is poor. Any way to find out whats wrong?

Tags: macos

My 10-year-old iMac, running High Sierra, has been beach balling a lot while using Safari and other applications. I ran Etrecheck on my computer and it said my performance was poor. When I look up what that meant it gave me the following:

> Poor: Your machine is critically sick. You should make a backup or
>   otherwise save critical documents immediately. Your machine likely
>   needs hardware repair.

I have run it several times and keep getting performance is poor. Is Etrecheck considered good and if so, is there any way to tell what in particular it was referring to

Comment: A 10 year old iMac has a spinning hard drive - usually a 5400 RPM.  I've never been a fan of Entrecheck because it's too vague to be of any use.  I'd start with a quick inventory of your current config.  High Sierra  is actually very stable - Catalina, IMO introduces much more issues than it solves (i.e. 32bit compatibility).

Comment: Etrecheck may usually be vague - but that warning seems pretty certain something is about to die. Make sure your backup is up to date. Then run SMART tests on the drive to see if that's what's failing. I wouldn't mess with anything like downgrading the OS until you know for certain what is wrong - it might just be the final straw.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Etrecheck is usually pretty reliable.

Your iMac is running on one of the latest software versions on a 10 year-old machine.

Your iMac is too old to handle the latest software and to support peak performance therefore Etrecheck is displaying that message.

If you can I recommend downgrading your OS to an older version, one that your iMac can handle better. You can see how to downgrade in [this article](https://www.makeuseof.com/tag/downgrade-macos-version/).

If you don’t want to downgrade I still recommend creating a backup for your files.

An additional test you can run is an [Apple Hardware Test](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201257), by holding the <kbd>D</kbd> key on startup which might detect any other issues.

Comment: it was recommended by Apple I upgrade. High Sierra is as far as I can go.  I've been running High Sierra without issue since it came out.  Now, this has started.

Comment: @jmh have you downloaded any power intensive apps recently? Have you checked in activity monitor what is running gin the background?

Comment: Not sure what the problem with @jmh's computer is but I have a mid-2011 iMac running nicely on High Sierra and I plan to use it for at least another year or two. Note, however, I had its memory upgraded to 20 GB a while ago and its hard disk to an SSD.